# how to store a video on to a my server and then how can i get the rtsp links for that video

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I am looking to make a application which will take a video and store that video to the server.till now i am able to store the video onto my sd-card. The problem is i don't no how to store the video onto the server. I have my website and that is hosted at some other server.so i want to store the video on to that server.can i store the video directly by giving the address as "www.begoniainfosys.com/video3.3gp".

and the second problem is how can i get a rtsp link for this video .i have seen a rtsp link from the youtube.but for my video how can i get i rtsp link so that i can stream.shall i install any streaming software at the server such as

darwin streaming server  or

wowza media server

Please help me achieving this.